# iOS simulator does not have internet connection

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

When starting an iOS simulator, it is not possible to get a HTTP response. Safari keeps showing the loading bar and does not load everything. I first though that it was my own application, but I tested it on multiple simulators, and all the simulators did not received any internet responses.

This problem is both on my MacBook Pro as my Mac mini at the office. is this a bug in the simulator, or do I have to turn something on?

**Simulator version**

```
Version 12.5 (961.1)
SimulatorKit 609
CoreSimulator 757.3
```

**Xcode version:**

```
Version 12.5 beta 2 (12E5234g)
```

[image]

Comment: If you're not already, it's best to use HTTPS wherever possible on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is a bug in Xcode Version 12.5 beta 2. It should be solved in beta 3

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674191